# If value is duplicated in one column, how can I extract some values of another column into a new one?

Tags: r, dplyr

Apologies for the awful title wording. I have some data that looks like this (grouped by id), where the 'question' column contains a number of repeats:

[image]

```
structure(list(study_id = c("02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", 
"02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", 
"0bsilzm5iabdnoj", "0bsilzm5iabdnoj", "0bsilzm5iabdnoj", "0bsilzm5iabdnoj", 
"0bsilzm5iabdnoj", "0bsilzm5iabdnoj", "1171bwmljjct6me", "1171bwmljjct6me", 
"1171bwmljjct6me", "1171bwmljjct6me", "1171bwmljjct6me", "1171bwmljjct6me"
), question = c("37tlJa09k7zwKFL ", "37tlJa09k7zwKFL", "3WTpbAzIQmbnlpb ", 
"3WTpbAzIQmbnlpb", "3eEVJgaAP6c9FPL ", "3eEVJgaAP6c9FPL", "7QhOyTdA1MjKmX3 ", 
"7QhOyTdA1MjKmX3", "8eMvvNHEh1CAqk5 ", "8eMvvNHEh1CAqk5", "e3u9ZmoNISb0vfn ", 
"e3u9ZmoNISb0vfn", "3IDmpN1FZDQqhcF ", "3IDmpN1FZDQqhcF", "3WRNXeyBSwuXvh3 ", 
"3WRNXeyBSwuXvh3", "6QnjC0CHjV1kmvX ", "6QnjC0CHjV1kmvX"), response = c("0.839", 
"word", "0.739", "word", "1.353", "picture", "1.418", "word", 
"1.563", "word", "6.377", "word", "1.795", "picture", "1.876", 
"picture", "0.96", "picture")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(study_id = c("02ipnnqgeovkrxz", 
"02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", 
"02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "0bsilzm5iabdnoj", "0bsilzm5iabdnoj", "0bsilzm5iabdnoj", 
"0bsilzm5iabdnoj", "0bsilzm5iabdnoj", "0bsilzm5iabdnoj", "1171bwmljjct6me", 
"1171bwmljjct6me", "1171bwmljjct6me", "1171bwmljjct6me", "1171bwmljjct6me", 
"1171bwmljjct6me"), question = c("37tlJa09k7zwKFL", "37tlJa09k7zwKFL ", 
"3eEVJgaAP6c9FPL", "3eEVJgaAP6c9FPL ", "3WTpbAzIQmbnlpb", "3WTpbAzIQmbnlpb ", 
"7QhOyTdA1MjKmX3", "7QhOyTdA1MjKmX3 ", "8eMvvNHEh1CAqk5", "8eMvvNHEh1CAqk5 ", 
"e3u9ZmoNISb0vfn", "e3u9ZmoNISb0vfn ", "3IDmpN1FZDQqhcF", "3IDmpN1FZDQqhcF ", 
"3WRNXeyBSwuXvh3", "3WRNXeyBSwuXvh3 ", "6QnjC0CHjV1kmvX", "6QnjC0CHjV1kmvX "
), .rows = list(2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 12L, 
    11L, 14L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 18L, 17L)), row.names = c(NA, -18L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I'm trying to reformat the data so that - within each grouped id - each row of the 'question' column is unique. Multiple responses made toward the same question are split into another column:

[image]

The 'question' column represents unique items the participant saw, and should not be repeated within id (since subjects only saw each item once). The response column represents their response to that item (picture / word) - but right now their reaction times are also lumped into this column. I'm basically looking to grab the reaction times and put them in a new column (that still corresponds with the appropriate id and question).

A tidyverse solution would be great, though any guidance would be much appreciated! I've tried a few variations of 'spread' / 'summarise' but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Please add data with `dput(head(df,n))` not **images**. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `base` solution:

```
#Data manipulation
df$study_id <- trimws(df$study_id)
df$question <- trimws(df$question)
df$response <- trimws(df$response)
df$Index <- as.numeric(df$response)
df$Index2 <- ifelse(is.na(df$Index),'response','rt')
df$Index <- NULL
df <- as.data.frame(df)
#Reshape
DataG <- reshape(df, idvar=c('study_id','question'), timevar='Index2', direction="wide")
DataG <- DataG[,c(1,2,4,3)]
rownames(DataG)<-NULL

         study_id        question response.response response.rt
1 02ipnnqgeovkrxz 37tlJa09k7zwKFL              word       0.839
2 02ipnnqgeovkrxz 3WTpbAzIQmbnlpb              word       0.739
3 02ipnnqgeovkrxz 3eEVJgaAP6c9FPL           picture       1.353
4 0bsilzm5iabdnoj 7QhOyTdA1MjKmX3              word       1.418
5 0bsilzm5iabdnoj 8eMvvNHEh1CAqk5              word       1.563
6 0bsilzm5iabdnoj e3u9ZmoNISb0vfn              word       6.377
7 1171bwmljjct6me 3IDmpN1FZDQqhcF           picture       1.795
8 1171bwmljjct6me 3WRNXeyBSwuXvh3           picture       1.876
9 1171bwmljjct6me 6QnjC0CHjV1kmvX           picture        0.96
```

Comment: Many thanks - I adapted this slightly to fit in with my tidyverse pipes, and it seems to work great :) 
`df <- df  %>% mutate(temp_index = as.double(response)) %>%
        mutate(index = ifelse(is.na(temp_index),'response','rt')) %>%
        select(-temp_index) %>%
        as.data.frame()
    df <- reshape(df, idvar=c('study_id','question'), timevar='index', direction="wide") %>%
      as_tibble(df, .name_repair)`

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is to create another variable specifying the type of the response, then to use `dcast` from `data.table` to reshape your data.

Like that, assuming `df` is your dataframe :

```
#which is numeric and which is not
df$type_var <- is.na(as.numeric(df$response)) 
df$type_var <- ifelse(df$type_var,"rt","response") # replacing with labels

#reshaping
data.table::dcast(df, id + question ~ type_var, value.var="response")
```

Comment: I understand the logic behind this - thanks. But the final line results in the following error for me:

Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
In addition: Warning message:
In data.table::dcast(df, id + question ~ type_var, value.var = "response") :
  The dcast generic in data.table has been passed a grouped_df and will attempt to redirect to the reshape2::dcast; please note that reshape2 is deprecated, and this redirection is now deprecated as well. Please do this redirection yourself like reshape2::dcast(df). In the next version, this warning will become an error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every question has 2 rows: 1st for numeric response, and 2nd for character response, then we can subset by alternating rows then column bind:

```
ix <- rep_len(c(FALSE, TRUE), nrow(df))
cbind(df[ix, ], rt = as.numeric(unlist(df[!ix, 3])))

#          study_id        question response    rt
# 1 02ipnnqgeovkrxz 37tlJa09k7zwKFL     word 0.839
# 2 02ipnnqgeovkrxz 3WTpbAzIQmbnlpb     word 0.739
# 3 02ipnnqgeovkrxz 3eEVJgaAP6c9FPL  picture 1.353
# 4 0bsilzm5iabdnoj 7QhOyTdA1MjKmX3     word 1.418
# 5 0bsilzm5iabdnoj 8eMvvNHEh1CAqk5     word 1.563
# 6 0bsilzm5iabdnoj e3u9ZmoNISb0vfn     word 6.377
# 7 1171bwmljjct6me 3IDmpN1FZDQqhcF  picture 1.795
# 8 1171bwmljjct6me 3WRNXeyBSwuXvh3  picture 1.876
# 9 1171bwmljjct6me 6QnjC0CHjV1kmvX  picture 0.960
```